# Elasticsearch sink connector task failed as any of the connection URL is down

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, elastic-stack, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have 3 node elasticsearch cluster. I am adding all 3 machines in Elasticsearch Sink connector config like below

"connection.url" : "http://es-node:9200,http://es-node2:9200,http://es-node3:9200"

But  whenever the first node is down, the task fails and though the node 2 and 3 are up and running.

Comment: Pretty sure this is by design. Do you know if the Elasticsearch Java client has settings itself to handle this any differently?

Comment: Any fix you have found for this??